# Deserialize json into wrapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Let's say, I have the following wrapper class:

```
public class StringWrapper {
    private final String regex;
    private String value;

    public StringWrapper(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        String validatedValue = SomeHelper.validate(regex, value);
        this.value = validatedValue;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and the following Object:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public StringWrapper value1 = new StringWrapper("[0-9A-Z]{3}");
    public StringWrapper value2 = new StringWrapper("[A-Z]{0, 10}");
}
```

Now I would like to serialize it with jackson-json to get the following structure:

```
{
    "value1": "ABC",
    "value2": "DEF",
}
```

That's easy with a custom serializer:

```
public static class StringWrapperSerializer extends JsonSerializer<StringWrapper> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(StringWrapper wrapper, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(wrapper.getValue());
    }
}
```

But how can I deserialize it? I don't want to serialize/deserialize the regex (and potential other attributes). I just want to serialize/deserialize the value. And I don't want to serialize/deserialize it as a substructure. The json-format should hide the wrapper.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever tried `JsonDeserializer`? You can simply use `ObjectMapper#readValue()` to deserialize it.

Comment: Try [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html).

Comment: I have not tried it, but I am pretty sure that it wont work. JsonDeserializer works with Reflection and wants to create a StringWrapper. But then I have also to serialize the whole StringWrapper, what I do not want to do.

Comment: JsonUnwrapped sounds interessting! Will give it a try.

Comment: @JsonUnwrapped does not work. The result is:
    {
        "value": "ABC", "value": "DEF"
    }

I need value1 and value2. :-/

Comment: I'm just wondering what you are trying to achieve with that.

Comment: My Object-Structure is a combination of the value and some meta-informations, like the format (used for validation) in one "scope".

Comment: Is a `Map<String, StringWrapper>` an option?

Comment: No, not really. I love the compiler safety.

Comment: One option is to create a setter for each attribute with the wrapped type. This works. But it's not so elegant...